# How to print TRUNC(SYSDATE)

Tags: sql

how can I get `SQL` to return me the value of `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` I know in unix it would be `echo` does SQL have an equivalent?

Cheers,

Comment: do you want to return (then where) or print (again where)?

Comment: `SELECT` is how you return data in SQL.

Comment: try `select trunc(sysdate) from dual` (oracle requires use of the `dual` `dummy table when selecting literals)

Comment: "SQL" (the query language) has no concept of "printing" or "displaying" data. The only thing "SQL" (the query language) can do is to modify or query data. "Printing" the results is always done by the application that _sends_ the SQL and processes the result that the server returns.

Answer (score 2):

For Oracle:

```
select trunc(sysdate) from dual;
```

(like stated above Oracle requires a dummy table "dual")